# Installation wizard - while a package installation, loader keep on showing and never end

Tags: installation, packages

`Installation Wizard` - while installing any package, 'Installing..' loader keep on showing even small size of package and never ending installation.

[image]

This happening in my local development(`Sitecore 8.1`) environment. Actually it is completing installation but not hiding loader.

Anyone know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Post your logfiles

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Have you tried [any of the solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17041253/1304050)?

Comment: Thanks @Dan Sinclair. Its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was due to no write access onto `temp` folder inside virtual directory(website folder).

In the `InstallPackageForm` class, the function `WatchForInstallationStatus()` is responsible for the "Job started: WatchStatus" logmessage. This function starts a new thread in which it checks the status of the package installation which is stored in the `temp` folder.

In my case,the `IIS_IUSRS` role did not have `write` access on the temp folder inside website. After I give permission on it, things are working.

**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041253/sitecore-package-install-never-ends